# Finding a Fusion Table entry with a geocoded address

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a Fusion Tables table containing location data for all of the Congressional Districts in Minnesota [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S488484plf1).

I want to have a user enter her address, have the Google Maps API geocode it, and spit out the district in which she lives from the table.

I had hoped I could just pick the closest district by using `orderBy: ST_DISTANCE` in the query. However, this doesn't always return the district the address is actually located in. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/2vGSB/

Assuming it's even possible, how might I return the district that a set of coordinates is located inside of?

**EDIT**

After digging through the documentation a bit, I found `where: ST_INTERSECTS`. It appears to be doing what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/DY49c/

Comment: Haven't used ST_DISTANCE but your example implies that there is a problem with it.  Perhaps an issue with zero values ...

Comment: My (wholly uneducated) guess is that it measures the distance to the closest center of a shape, or the closest starting point of a shape, as opposed to the actually closest shape.